# Can I compile LÖVE games into EXE files and sell them?

Tags: lua, love2d

I've got two questions about [LÖVE](http://love2d.org).

Can I sell what I make in LÖVE? Can I compile anything I make into an EXE file?

Comment: For the next time, in such questions please simply add a [link to the program](http://love2d.org/), since not everyone wants to have to google it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can sell what you make in LÖVE. Their site clearly says: "LÖVE is licensed under the liberal zlib/libpng license. That means you can use it freely for any purpose — including commercial ones."

And yes, you can make an executable out of your LÖVE project. Just see [here](http://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution).

Comment: Thanks so much!  You answered second but got both questions!  ANSWERED!

Answer (score 18):

Here's the answer to your EXE file question from [their wiki](http://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution):

> **Windows**
>
> copy /b love.exe+game.love game.exe
>
> **Linux**
>
> cat love game.love > game

From their [TOS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TOS#Noun):

> Permission is hereby granted, **free of
> charge**, to any person...  to deal in
> the Software without restriction,
> including without limitation the
> rights to use, copy, modify, merge,
> publish, distribute, sublicense,
> and/or **sell copies of the Software**,...
> subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
> **permission notice shall be included** in
> all copies or substantial portions of
> the Software.

It says you can do anything you want with it as long as you leave their permissions notices in-tact on any files they put it on.

Comment: Thanks!  Even though you posted first, Tovi7 above got both.  Here is a vote up for you :)

Comment: I've got a hunch that the Linux line, `cat love game.love > game` won't work, as probably the love executable isn't in the same dir as the game.love file. So it should be `cat \`which love\` game.love > game`

Answer (score 6):

From the same page -

> Two things should be noted:
>
> - The end result will not be a single executable, you must also include some DLL files in your zip-file.
> - The resulting executable from the merge will still be **readable by archiving software, such as WinZip.**

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, you can sell the games for any price
2. yes, you can compile them into `.exe` files through

`copy /b (love.exe file location here)+(.love file location here) game.exe` for windows and

`cat (love.exe file location here) (.love file location here) > game.exe` for linux,

in the folder where you put .exe file be sure to copy/paste the `.dll` files into said folder